# NullPointer Exception on using epublib

Tags: java, android, slf4j, epublib

I use Paul Siegman's epublib to render ePubs in my application.  I get a NullPointerException when I try

```
Bitmap coverImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(book.getCoverImage().getInputStream());
```

My search returned that I should import slf4j api and simple library along with the android library.  I downloaded the latest .jars from slf4j.org (v 1.7.6)

My build.gradle looks like this:

```
compile files('libs/epublib-core-latest.jar')
compile files('libs/slf4j-simple-1.7.6.jar')
compile files('libs/slf4j-android-1.7.6.jar')
compile files('libs/slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar')
```

I get an error when I build

```
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder;
```

I tried removing the simple library and the project builds. But when I remove the -simple library, I get the NullPointerException.

Comment: when you get the NPE, what is null ?

Comment: The getCoverImage returns null.  But my epub's opf contains the cover image.